Add Rows based on user input in Column/ Cell Value and Copy Formulas Down
I'm trying to add rows below every time a cell within a specific column, based on user input in Application.InputBox, has a value "Start".
The worksheet may have multiple instances of "Start" in the same column so I need multiple rows created below the "start" row.
I also need the formulas from the row where "Start" appears to copy down into the rows just created.
Code 1 asks for user input for the column where the value "Start" is but only adds one new row and does not copy the formulas down.
Code 2 asks for user input for the # of rows and row to start, it does not look for the column value I need for reference and won't copy the formulas down.
Both codes work but is there a way to add to code 1 or combine these into one and add the "copy formulas" portion?
I click a button to start the code.
The quantity and location of "Start" is dynamic but always within the same column.
Worksheet names are never the same.
The width of data/formulas in each row is dynamic.
Code 1
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
   
    xTitleId = "Enter the value"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "Start" Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Code 2
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCount As Long
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next

iCount = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many rows you want to add?")
iRow = Application.InputBox _
  (Prompt:="After which row you want to add new rows? (Enter the row number")

For i = 1 To iCount
    Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Insert  
Next i

End Sub



Validating user input is essential to ensure the robustness of the code.
Use FillDown to apply formulas on inserted rows

Microsoft documentation:

Range.FillDown method (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows()
    Dim Rng As Range, xTitleId As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range, xLastRow As Long, xRowIndex As Long
    Dim iRow, iCount
    Dim i As Long
    xTitleId = "Enter the value"
    iCount = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="How many rows you want to add?")
    If (Not IsNumeric(iCount)) Or Val(iCount) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    iRow = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="After which row you want to add new rows? (Enter the row number)")
    If (Not IsNumeric(iRow)) Or Val(iRow) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set WorkRng = Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Dim formulaRng As Range
    Set formulaRng = WorkRng.Resize(1, WorkRng.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Row > iRow Then
            If Rng.Value = "Start" Then
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCount).EntireRow.Insert
                Intersect(Rng.Resize(iCount + 1).EntireRow, formulaRng).FillDown
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Testing Input:
How many rows you want to add: 2
After which row you want to add new rows: 4
Selecct Range: $A$2:$B$14



Update2:

Assuming Start is on the first col of the table.
Add code to remove Start on the inserted rows

Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows2()
    Dim Rng As Range, xTitleId As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range, xLastRow As Long, xRowIndex As Long
    Dim iRow, iCount, i As Long
    Const COL_INDEX = 2
    xTitleId = "Enter the value"
    iCount = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="How many rows you want to add?")
    If (Not IsNumeric(iCount)) Or Val(iCount) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    iRow = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="After which row you want to add new rows? (Enter the row number)")
    If (Not IsNumeric(iRow)) Or Val(iRow) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim formulaRng As Range
    If WorkRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then _
        Set formulaRng = WorkRng.Resize(1, WorkRng.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(COL_INDEX)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Row > iRow Then
            If Rng.Value = "Start" Then
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCount).EntireRow.Insert
                If Not formulaRng Is Nothing Then
                    Intersect(Rng.Resize(iCount + 1).EntireRow, formulaRng).FillDown
                    Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCount).ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Thanks. I'll try this and respond back as soon as possible.....Thanks AGAIN!!!

@mikeF thanks again for the code....It is very close to what i need. It appears that i need to select the entire range that is applicable. I apologize if i was not specific enough.

The logic of Code 2 is incorrect.  i need to select the entire range that is applicable - It's from your Code 1. Of course, we can remove it. But the question is how to determine the location (which column) of Start w/o user selection.

so on code 1 original, when asked to select the range, i would select all of column B:B. "Start" appears throughout that column depending on multiple formulas. Again, Code 1 does what i need it to do, i just need to add multiple rows from time to time, and pull the formulas that occur within that "Start" row......i'll try this and respond again, and thanks SO MUCH!

The new code does not give and error but it also doesn't seem to do anything that i can see. I did note that the code still asks for the "...row to start...". that is not needed for Code 1. Code 1 asks for the range and i select column B:B, then it automatically adds only one row below every instance of "Start", which is in column B.

I'm lost. I suggest specifying the entire procedure to clarify the user's input and the expected output. My new code ONLY works for Start is on the first column of table. You can test it with the same data set as my screenshot.

@Taller...i apologize, i did not see your note stating that "Start" is assumed to be on the 1st column. I updated to Column B and the code works without issue. Is there a way to not copy the word "Start" on each row created? i have a formula that will somewhat do what i need but wasn't sure about VBA?
Thanks again everyone for the combined help on this!!!! what a great forum!

Thank You!!!!! This is excellent! I accepted the updated answer. If there is anything else you need me to do, let me know. Sincerely appreciate all the help once again!
